# Extract coefficient and p-value for certain variable from regression loop

Tags: loops, regression, linear-regression, stata

In Stata have applied a regression loop to 1000 metabolites (outcome), and the exposure variable is BMI. I also have other variables in the model. I would like to know how I can extract only the coefficient, p-value, and 95% CI for BMI if and only aif BMI is significant. And then I want to extract them into an Excel file.

This is the code I have used. It informed me that there were, for example, 100 significant results. So I'm trying to figure out which 100 are those and extract them for BMI only, without other variables in the model.

```
    local counter = 0
local counter_pos = 0
local counter_neg = 0

foreach outcome of varlist B - Z {
   regress `outcome' bmi Age i.sex i.smoking i.lpa2c i.cholestrol
    matrix M = r(table)
    if M[4, 1] < 0.05 {
        local ++counter
        if _b[bmi] < 0 {
            local ++counter_neg
        }
        else {
            local ++counter_pos
        }
    }
}



display as text "Total of significant results: " as result `counter'
```

Comment: Do you want to save the list of outcome variables with conventionally significant results? In general, or separately by positive or negative coefficients, You can use `postfile` to add values of a string variable to a dataset of results.

Comment: @NickCox Yes for all significant results. I want the names of these significant and only extract values for BMI.

Comment: @NickCox I tried to use the command you have suggested but I don't know if I have enter it in the right way because I didn't receive any results.

Comment: We need to see your code to give precise advice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reproducible example showing how to send a variable name and some results to a new file. In your case, posting is conditional on a conventionally significant result; here it is unconditional.

```
sysuse auto, clear 

local counter = 0 
local negative = 0 
local positive = 0 

tempname RESULTS 
postfile `RESULTS' str32 varname coefficient using myresults.dta, replace  

foreach v in price mpg rep78 headroom trunk length turn displacement gear_ratio { 
    quietly regress `v' weight 
    local ++counter
    if _b[weight] < 0 local ++negative
    else local ++positive 
    post `RESULTS' ("`v'") (_b[weight]) 
} 

di "variables tried:   " `counter' 
di "negative relation: " `negative' 
di "positive relation: " `positive'  

postclose `RESULTS' 

use myresults, clear 
compress 
list
```